# CSS selector to pass partial tag name to find the element

Tags: css, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I am trying to find an element with the following html

```
<first-name-grid>
<div> some text .. </div>
</first-name-grid>
```

I want to know a way to write CSS locator to find first-name-grid like I'm able to find out using xpath

```
let firstNameXpathLocator : string = `//*[contains(name(),'first-name')]`;
```

Answer (score 0):

The CSS Selector for

```
<first-name-grid>
```

is

```
first-name-grid {...}
```

---

You won't be able to select an element using a fragment of the element name,  but you *can* use this as an alternative:

**Element:**

```
<first-name-grid data-element="first-name-grid">
```

**Selector:**

```
[data-element*="first-name"] {...}
```

In this instance `*=` signifies CONTAINS.